# Efficient way to perform a 2D x 1D Matrix Multiply

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to perform a 2D by 1D matrix multiply. Specifically:

```
import numpy as np

s = np.ones(268)
one_d = np.ones(9422700)
s_newaxis = s[:, np.newaxis]
goal = s_newaxis * one_d
```

While the dimensions above are the same as my problem (`(268, 1)` and `(9422700,)`), the actual values in my arrays are a mix of very large and very small numbers. As a result I *can* run `goal = s_newaxis * one_d` because only 1s exist. However, I *run out of ram* using my actual data.

I recognize that, at the end of the day, this amounts to a matrix with ~2.5 billion values and so a heavy memory footprint is to be expected. However, any improvement in terms of efficiency would be welcome.

---

For completeness, I've included a *rough* attempt. It is not very elegant, but it is just enough of an improvement that it won't crash my computer (admittedly a low bar).

```
import gc

def arange(start, stop, step):
    # `arange` which includes the endpoint (`stop`).
    arr = np.arange(start=start, stop=stop, step=step)
    if arr[-1] < stop:
        return np.append(arr, [stop])
    else:
        return arr

left, all_arrays = 0, list()
for right in arange(0, stop=s_newaxis.shape[0], step=10):
    chunk = s_newaxis[left:right,:] * one_d
    all_arrays.append(chunk)
    left = right
    gc.collect()  # unclear if this makes any difference...I suspect not.

goal = np.vstack(all_arrays)
```

Comment: The values in the arrays have no effect on the memory consumption. If you're running out of RAM in your actual program, it's because you're using more of it on other things.

Comment: What happens if you do : `out = np.empty((268,9422700))`? If that works out, then try `out[:] = s[:,None]` and finally `out *= one_d`.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for correcting my intuition there.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks -- that was a huge improvement. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: And `s[:, np.newaxis]* one_d` threw memory error?

Comment: It doesn't even get that far -- it simply depletes my RAM and a healthy amount of swap.

Comment: I am not clear, at which point do you get memory error? I thought it was at : `s_newaxis * one_d`.

Comment: Sorry for any ambiguity. Numpy never explicitly throws a memory error. The operations simply eats up so much memory my computer chews through 4-6gb of RAM, a huge amount of swap, and crashes.

Comment: I am not sure if my earlier suggested codes in comment would be helpful for future readers in a similar situation. But since that worked for you, consider posting that as your own answer post. Feel free to use those codes from the comment.

Comment: What are you actually using ``goal`` for? If you are doing other downstream linear algebra calculations, I suspect they can be simplified to where you do not need to explicitly compute it. There are very few cases when it makes sense to explicitly store a rank one matrix.